# Change Close button in window form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to change the command of the (x) Button?

I want to show another form and hide the current form instead of closing the program.

where should I put this? :

```
Me.Hide()
Form.Show()
```

I tried puttin it on the Form Closing/Closed Event, but nothing happen, am I missing something?

Comment: Can you show the code you tried in the Closing/Closed event(s)?

Comment: "am I missing something" - the `e.Cancel` - see Hans Passant's answer. (But pay attention to what he wrote: "you have to give a way for your user to terminate the app"!)

Answer (score 2):

Sure, the FormClosing event is made to do that.  You'll need to pay attention to the reason the form is being closed, something like this:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnFormClosing(ByVal e As FormClosingEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnFormClosing(e)
    If Not e.Cancel AndAlso e.CloseReason = CloseReason.UserClosing Then
        e.Cancel = True
        Dim frm = New Form2()
        frm.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End If
End Sub
```

Do note that you have to give a way for your user to terminate the app.

Comment: sorry if it takes too long for me to reply, sir Hans your codes do worked but I have a problem, when I'm declaring the `Me.Close` it's not working. I want to put it in another button instead in the (X) red button